# Android doesn't recognize french characters

Tags: android, string, localization

For example, I want to write this text in string element in `strings-fr.xml` file:

```
est la radio en ligne fondé par DJ Le Gammeltoft. Poussé par la passion pour la musique l'ancien hôte Unga Bunga continue présenter de grands titres de sa propre plate-forme
```

I got the error:

```
error: Apostrophe not preceded by \ (in HEARTBEATS est la radio en ligne fondأ© par DJ Le Gammeltoft. Poussأ© par la passion pour la musique l'ancien hأ´te Unga Bunga continue prأ©senter de grands titres de sa propre 
 plate-forme.)
```

How could it be corrected?

Comment: That has nothing to do with French. You've got `'` in that text, and the parser is complaining they're not escaped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be work:

```
<string name="sample">est la radio en ligne fondé par DJ Le Gammeltoft. Poussé par la passion pour la musique l\'ancien hôte Unga Bunga continue présenter de grands titres de sa propre plate-forme
</string>
```